# android searchable not opening

Tags: android, search, searchable

Hi im trying to use a searchable activity in my application but when the search button is pressed nothing happens

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.test.test" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Test">
            <activity android:name=".Test" android:label="Test" android:debuggable="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:launchMode="singleTask">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".Searchable">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
            </activity>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".Searchable"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Searchable.xml (res/xml/searchable.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:label="Search" android:hint="Perform Search">
    </searchable>
```

Searchable.java (src/com/test/test/Searchable.java)

```
package com.test.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Searchable extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        }
    }
}
```

TIA,

ng93

Comment: Aren't you forgetting to show a View?  Like: setContentView(R.layout.main);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Searchable` activity has to do something - and actually display results.

I just wrote one as suggested by an answer to a question I asked yesterday [Trying to filter a ListView with runQueryOnBackgroundThread but nothing happens - what am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571401/trying-to-filter-a-listview-with-runqueryonbackgroundthread-but-nothing-happens/4571791#4571791)

Look at this documentation for how to integrate with the built in search support: [Using the Android Search Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) and look at this article on how to offer suggestions as the customer types: [Adding Custom Suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html)

Your class `Searchable` needs to do a bit more after getting the query string.  For example in my activity after getting the query string I do this:

```
        showResults(query);
```

and that method looks like this:

```
private void showResults(String query)  {
    //  Load the list of countries based on the query
    Cursor countryCursor = myDbHelper.getCountryList (query);
    startManagingCursor (countryCursor);

    //  Hook up the query results to the list view
    String[] from = new String[]  {
        WorldInfoDatabaseAdapter.KEY_COUNTRYCODE, WorldInfoDatabaseAdapter.KEY_COUNTRYNAME
    };
    int[] to = new int[]  {
        R.id.countryflag, R.id.countryname
    };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this,
            R.layout.country_list_row, countryCursor, from, to);
    adapter.setViewBinder (new FlagViewBinder ());

    myCountryList.setAdapter (adapter);
    myCountryList.setOnItemClickListener (new OnItemClickListener () {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String countryName = myDbHelper.getCountryByID (id);
            if (countryName == null)  {
                new AlertDialog.Builder (SelectCountryActivity.this).setMessage (
                        "Internal error: Cannot find the country with id'" + id + "'.").show ();

                return;
            }

            //  Package up the country name to return
            Intent newCountryIntent = new Intent (myCountryList.getContext (), WorldInfoActivity.class);
            newCountryIntent.putExtra (WorldInfoActivity.KEY_SELECTED_COUNTRY, countryName);
            startActivity (newCountryIntent);

            startActivity (newCountryIntent);
            finish ();
        }
    });
}
```

The member myDbHelper queries my database for countries that have the passed in query string and displays them in a list.  My activity has a layout that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="?pageBackground">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selectdlgtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/select_country_title"
        style="?dlgTitle" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/countrylist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:padding="2px"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

You can probably do without the `setViewBinder` call - I need that because I am translating the country code field into a flag icon.

Comment: Thanks but still can't get it to work. I've added System.out.println("Searching"); to onCreate() and onNewIntent() but not seeing them either.

Comment: I was just reading more on this topic this morning and I remember several people saying that the could not get it to work with constant strings in the searchable.xml file.  Two people reported that with constant strings they spent a long time debugging and it never worked.  When they switched to string resources everything was good.

Comment: @ng93 @lanLeslie Hi, I am facing the same problem, and I am actually using string resources in the searchable.xml, and also printing the query string in a textview in a method like `showResults` in your example. [here is my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567796/android-assisted-search-the-search-button-does-not-invoke-the-searchable-activi), can I be suggested something?